# detect when an input in a tablesorter table is focused on

Tags: php, javascript

I have a tablesorter table, which works correctly, however, I need to know when a text field is focused on so I can capture the value there.  The reason for this is that I need to make sure the value is not changed to more than 10% of the original value.  I was trying to use the focus event and calling an alert, as shown by the following code:

```
    $('#price').focus(function(){ alert("Blur works");
});
```

When i focus on the field, nothing is firing. #price is the id of the text field in my table.
Ultimately I think I can use this code to accomplish what I want, but I am open to any suggestion.

```
     $('#price').focus(function(){ 
var tempPrice = $(this).find('#price').val();
$('#price').change(function(){
    if ($(this).find('#price').val() > (tempPrice+(tempPrice*.1))){
    $('#price').val(tempPrice);
    }
});
}); //end of blur function
```

I have looked at the other questions that are similar and nothing seems to be working for me.
I am using JS and php for the main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I managed to solve the problem of not being able to select any row except the first one, after much trial and error:

```
    $('#tally tr').live ('click', function(){
var tempPrice =0;
 tempPrice = $(this).find('#price').val();
```

I am still working on the rest of the problem.